# Restheart consumers in production

Tags: restheart

Are there any consumers for Restheart in production. We are planning to use it in our company and wanted to understand the performance in production and any issues faced.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Comment: I'm biased because I'm one of the developers behind RESTHeart. We are in production with several customers since almost 3 years now, with different versions. No issues so far, especially not in terms of performances. Here you can read a document we wrote in 2015: https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/gICM (it's a bit old but still valid).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will you be able to give references? The reason I am asking is - we are also looking at Dreamfactory and they list the consumers here -https://www.dreamfactory.com/company/customers. We wanted something similar from restheart